# How to implement IBM MQ Light on javascript client

Tags: javascript, ibm-mq, ibm-cloud

I deploy MQ Light service on bluemix, and I want to send message from server using python to browser client. Is there any standalone javascript library to use on browser web UI?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running a full MQ Light javascript library in your browser (which would also need to know the credentials of your Bluemix service, which you don't want to share), you could run the MQ Light code in the server (e.g. Node.js), and expose a REST API, or use other web technologies to get your data to the browser, such as WebSockets or Server-sent events.

Alternatively, you could use the Message Hub Bluemix service which has a built in REST API to do messaging.

Comment: I end up using http://socket.io for this, the message is free but cost me another instance to run node.js

Answer (score 0):

A Node.js client is available for IBM MQ Light as documented here: https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/mq-light/.

Comment: node.js is server side scripting, isn't it? what I need is front-end javascript library to embed on web page like mqtt implementation by paho here https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/js/